Symmertry of $R$-tensor of Stark Effect in diamond structure
Currently, I am studying the effects of electric fields on color centers in diamonds. However, I have encountered a problem: when addressing the Stark effect caused by the electric field, I use the R tensor to represent the energy level shifts caused by the Stark effect. However, I am unable to write out the specific form of the R tensor according to the C3v symmetry of the NV color center in diamond, or rather, to write out the non-zero elements of the R tensor. There is a table about the effects of symmetry on the R tensor, but I have not studied group theory and cannot understand the meaning of this table.

This is the electric field term in Hamitonian

